# Phonetics of labiodental / bilabial consonant cluster

Tags: phonetics

So someone asked me the following question.

> I was wondering why the letter "b" disappears when the Beatles sing:
>
> > "and I've ((b))een working like a dog"

I listened to the [Song](https://youtu.be/Yjyj8qnqkYI?t=1m12s) on YouTube for a few times and I hear a **b** being pronounced.

But I was wondering if it's diminished by two phonetically similar consonants v and b.

If there were two bilabial stops, a collapse of consonant clusters seems very plausible, but a labiodental doesn't stop airflow so there should be a clear pronunciation of the consonant **b** in "hav(e) (b)een"

Comment: In Ukrainian, _вбив_ “[I/you/he] killed” is pronounced [wbɪw] and always sounds definitely different from _бив_ “[I/you/he] beat/hit/struck” pronounced [bɪw].

Comment: The /b/ isn’t weakened – it’s fully pronounced (in the song too). The /v/ in _I’ve_ is often weakened and may disappear altogether (yielding _I been_), but that’s because auxiliaries are so archetypically unstressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, the prevocalic consonant would be perceptually most prominent since the release from near-silence to vowel is dramatic, however any clip taken from a Beatles concert is not exactly normal. There is a fair amount of background noise and the foreground signal is highly mixed. Of course, we know the lyrics to the song so we can supply a transcription, regardless of what the acoustic signal contains.

A focused extract of the segments in question is [here](https://voca.ro/1gHFbYq6Qa51). The first 180 msc is something vocalic, another vocalic section starts at 265 msc, and in between is expected [vb]. As you can see, this does not look like speech, and there is no hope of using conventional acoustic landmarks to identify segments based on the phonetic record. You can detect formant-lowering on the second vocalic stretch for some reason, but all there is of that consonant is a small decrease in amplitude

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMSiHdrHl0g) alternative (cleaner) source, the analogous stretch in [the extract](https://voca.ro/1eqOW1biKL8f) run up to 90 msc, then consonant until 165 msc. Again, no visible consonant release, but we can more clearly hear the following vocalic stretch as [ɪw...] – the labialization is from *w* of "workin(g)". It may sound like [β], but it does not look like [β]. We are more familiar with optical illusions like the bent stick in water one, but there are also auditory illusions. The cause of the illusion is most likely the lack of silence followed by a release burst. In other words, we first have to work out the relation between "how things sound to us" and "how the air actually moves".